# How to prove the minimum identity for finite number of real numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, order-theory, maxima-minima

I have trouble in proving the following statement: Let $n$ be an integer no less than 3, and $a_1,\dots, a_n$ be real numbers. 
 If $n$ is even, then
        \begin{align*}
   &\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_4\}+\cdots +\min\{a_{n-2}, a_{n-1},a_n\}\\
   &+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_5\}+\min\{a_2,\dots, a_6\}+\cdots+\min\{a_{n-4},\dots, a_n\}\\
   &+\cdots +\min\{a_1,\dots, a_{n-1}\}+\cdots +\min\{a_2,\dots, a_n\}\\
   &+\min\{a_2+\cdots+a_n, a_1+\widehat{a_2}+\cdots +a_n,\dots, a_1+\cdots +a_{n-1}+\widehat{a_n}\}\\
   =&\min\{a_1,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_4\}+\cdots+\min\{a_{n-1},a_n\}\\
   &+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_4\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_5\}+\cdots +\min\{a_{n-3},\dots, a_n\}\\
   &+\cdots+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_{n}\},\tag{1}
  \end{align*}
where the notation $\widehat{a_2}$ means that number $a_2$ is deleted.
        If $n$ is odd, then
        \begin{align*}
  &\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_4\}+\cdots +\min\{a_{n-2}, a_{n-1},a_n\}\\
  &+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_5\}+\min\{a_2,\dots, a_6\}+\cdots+\min\{a_{n-4},\dots, a_n\}\\
  &+\cdots +\min\{a_1,\dots, a_n\}\\
  &+\min\{a_2+\cdots+a_n, a_1+\widehat{a_2}+\cdots +a_n,\dots, a_1+\cdots +a_{n-1}+\widehat{a_n}\}\\
  =&\min\{a_1,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_4\}+\cdots+\min\{a_{n-1},a_n\}\\
  &+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_4\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_5\}+\cdots +\min\{a_{n-3},\dots, a_n\}\\
  &+\cdots+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_{n-1}\}+\cdots+\min\{a_2,\dots, a_n\}.\tag{2}
  \end{align*}
        For instance, if $n=5,$ then 
        \begin{align*}
   &\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_4\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_5\}+\min\{a_1,a_3,a_4\}\\
   &+\min\{a_1,a_3,a_5\}+\min\{a_1,a_4,a_5\}+\min\{a_2,a_3,a_4\}+\min\{a_2,a_3,a_5\}\\
   &+\min\{a_2,a_4,a_5\}+\min\{a_3,a_4,a_5\}+\min\{a_1,\dots, a_5\}\\
   &+\min\{a_2a_3a_4a_5,a_1a_3a_4a_5,a_1a_2a_4a_5,a_1a_2a_3a_5,a_1a_2a_3a_4\}\\
   =&\min\{a_1,a_2\}+\min\{a_1,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_4\}+\min\{a_1,a_5\}+\min\{a_2,a_3\}\\
   &+\min\{a_2,a_4\}+\min\{a_2,a_5\}+\min\{a_3,a_4\}+\min\{a_3,a_5\}+\min\{a_4,a_5\}\\
   &+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3,a_5\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_4,a_5\}\\
   &+\min\{a_1,a_3,a_4,a_5\}+\min\{a_2,a_3,a_4,a_5\},\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
        while if $n=4,$ then 
        \begin{align*}
  &\min\{a_1,a_2,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_2,a_4\}+\min\{a_1,a_3,a_4\}+\min\{a_2,a_3,a_4\}\\
  &+\min\{a_2a_3a_4, a_1a_3a_4, a_1a_2a_4,a_1a_2a_3\}\\
  =&\min\{a_1,a_2\}+\min\{a_1,a_3\}+\min\{a_1,a_4\}+\min\{a_2,a_3\}\\
  &+\min\{a_2,a_4\}+\min\{a_3,a_4\}+\min\{a_1,\dots,a_4\}.\tag{4}
  \end{align*}
Since (3) and (4) are both transpositionally symmetrical, and cyclically symmetrical, it is easy to prove (3) and (4), by just considering the case that $a_1\leq a_2\leq \cdots \leq a_5.$ But it is not so for (1) and (2). Who can help me? Or is there easier proof of (1) and (2)? I want to use these identities to prove an identity of GCD in elementary number theory, that is,
\begin{gather*}
\gcd\left(a_2a_3\cdots a_n, a_1a_3\cdots a_n,\dots, a_1\cdots a_{n-1}\right)=\cdots.
\end{gather*}

Comment: I feel like there could be an interesting question here but it is drowning in ellipses!  Is there a high-level description you can give for which terms belong to the LHS and RHS?

Comment: What's the full identity of gcd you're proving?

Comment: So this is the sum of the minimum of all odd subsets?

Comment: @AlexFrancisco: If we can prove (1) and (2), then, by FTA(Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic),  the RHS can be given suddenly.  I just write the  four-number case: $\gcd(ab,bc,ca)\gcd(a,b,c)=\gcd(a,b)\gcd(a,c)\gcd(b,c).$